# Include fields in mongodb aggregate

Tags: mongodb, mongodb-query, aggregation-framework

I have the following collection:

```
{"orderID" : "30688", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "11396783", "customerEmail" : "foo@bar.com"}
{"orderID" : "30688", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "11396783", "customerEmail" : "foo@bar.com"}
{"orderID" : "30688", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "11396783", "customerEmail" : "foo@bar.com"}
{"orderID" : "89765", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "54157526", "customerEmail" : ""}
{"orderID" : "89765", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "54157526", "customerEmail" : ""}
{"orderID" : "21546", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "20103585", "customerEmail" : "xxx@yyy.com"}
{"orderID" : "21546", "branch" : "CO", "customerID" : "20103585", "customerEmail" : "xxx@yyy.com"}
{"orderID" : "21546", "branch" : "KA", "customerID" : "89374792", "customerEmail" : "aaa@ccc.com"}
{"orderID" : "21794", "branch" : "NY", "customerID" : "78125522", "customerEmail" : ""}
```

I need to get all unique customerIDs in a certain branch whose customerEmail is not null. What I expect for "branch":"CO"

```
{"customerID" : "11396783", "customerEmail" : "foo@bar.com"}
{"customerID" : "20103585", "customerEmail" : "xxx@yyy.com"}
```

So far I've tried:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { branch: "CO" } },   
    { $group:
        {
            _id: { customer:"$customerID"}
        }
    },
    {
        $group: {_id:"$_id.customer"}
    },
    {
        $addFields: {  email: "$customerEmail"} 
    }
]);
```

but it doesn't bring the email field.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It does not include the field because you did not ask for the field to return. The thing you are missing here is using [`$first`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/first/) or a similar ["accumulator"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators-group) in order to return the element during the [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/).

Also if you don't want the empty email address then exclude it within the [`$match`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/match/) pipeline stage, since that's the most efficient thing to do.

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { branch: "CO", "customerEmail": { "$ne": "" } } },
    { $group:
        {
            _id: { customer:"$customerID"},
            email: { "$first": "$customerEmail" }
        }
    }
]);
```

A "pipeline" only returns "output" from stages like [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) or [`$project`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/project/) that you actually ask it to. Just like the "Unix pipe" `|` operator, the only things available to the "next stage" are what you output.

This should be evident simply from:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { branch: "CO" } },   
    { $group:
        {
            _id: { customer:"$customerID"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Or even:

```
db.collection.aggregate([
    { $match: { branch: "CO" } },   
    { $project:
        {
            _id: { customer:"$customerID"}
        }
    }
]);
```

Which returns of course only the `_id` value since that is all you asked for.

You only have access in any pipeline stage to the data which was "output by the previous stage". Within a [`$group`](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/group/) that means only the `_id` for the grouping key, and whatever was specified **"explicitly"** using a valid ["accumulator"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators-group) for any other properties you wish to return. Any accumulator ( which is valid for a "string" here ) will do, but anything outside of the `_id` **must** use an ["accumulator"](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/#accumulators-group).

I suggest taking the time to look at all the [aggregation operators](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/aggregation/) and what they actually do. There is example usage with each operator